# How to solve T(n) = 2T(n-1) + n, T(0)=O(1)?

Tags: complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, recurrence-relation

I'm trying to solve this recurrence equation in this way:

$$ 
T(0)=O(1)\\
T(n) = 2T(n - 1) + n \\
 = 2[ 2T(n - 2) + (n - 1) ] + n \\
 = 2[ 2[ 2T( n - 3 ) + ( n - 2 ) ] + ( n - 1 ) ] + n \\
 = 2³T(n-3) + 2²(n-2) + 2(n-1) + n$$

And I get:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} 2^i(n-i) $$

That's right?

Comment: We already have detailed advice on how to solve recurrences. Checking your specific answer is off-topic here, since it's only ever going to be interesting to you.

Comment: I have a book with the same information, but that does not solve my question for this specific exercise, thank you.